# Spring Cloud Stream binder for AWS Kinesis and issues with getShardIterator

Tags: spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

We are receiving `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`s on the `getShardIterator` request while consuming from a Kinesis shard.  We noticed in the logs that the error occurs on a `getShardIterator` request being sent before a checkpoint occurs.  AWS support believes the `getShardIterator` in KCL is being called explicitly by the Spring code. Can you tell us if and why the `getShardIterator` would be called multiple times per second per shard while processing messages? Note that we are using Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis version 2.2.0.

Here's the reply we received from the AWS Kinesis team providing support to us:

> From the logs provided, I see that the ProvisonedThroughputExceededException errors are related to the GetShardIterator calls. When you read repeatedly from a stream, you use a GetShardIterator request to get the first shard iterator for use in your first GetRecords request and for subsequent reads use the shard iterator returned by the GetRecords request in NextShardIterator. A new shard iterator is returned by every GetRecords request in NextShardIterator, which you use in the ShardIterator parameter of the next GetRecords request. If a GetShardIterator request is made too often, you receive a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException, which we see happening here. GetShardIterator has a limit of five transactions per second per account per open shard.
>
> Every GetRecords call should not use the GetShardIterator API.
> Instead, it should use the previous GetRecords requests
> NextShardIterator response. Please note we are in discussion with the
> internal team on further guidance regarding these
> ProvisonedThroughputExceededException related to the GetShardIterator
> API.

Comment: That version of Kinesis Binder is out of support for years. I believe we had some changes in that regards between that and the current version, but it is hard at the moment to answer you what and exactly when happened with the code. So, better to look into an upgrade to the latest version. More over: we don't have control for KCL behavior in Kinesis Binder or even in the `KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. So, the puzzle may come back to AWS support again if you confirm that you use KCL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Artem. We are in the middle of an upgrade to the very latest Spring Cloud 2022.x, Spring Boot 3.x, Spring Cloud AWS 3.0, and Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis 4.0.0. Until we are upgraded, though, we have to run with this stack for now. I will update this thread with what we find out from AWS support.